# How do I update custom modules (PnP.Powershell) in Azure Runbook?

Tags: azure-runbook

I have an Azure automation account where a runbook uses PnP.Powershell which enables interfacing with SharePoint. However, due to a bug in an older version of PnP.Powershell, it doesn't support batching while using Add-PnPListItem. Consequently, I want to update my version of PnP.Powershell from 1.5 to 1.12.

However, I can't find any resources that point me towards updating custom modules in Azure Runbook. I can only find information on updating the AZ modules.

I thought of deleting the PnP module and importing it again but that automation account has several runbooks active and doing that would not be feasible. Please let me know if anyone has an idea of the best way to update the custom modules in Azure Runbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to update a custom module is by deleting and reimporting it.